# Mobile position in relation to each other

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7

Is there any library that can help me determine one mobiles devices position in relation to other?

For example:
Can one iPhone determine that there is another one laying next to it and if so which way is it facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do what you are asking.

NFC requires the devices to basically touch.  Wifi and GPS location services probably don't have the granularity to determine location to that precise level.  It would probably be possible to use the location services to determine if two phones were in the same room (not table), and which location.  I think in real world, this would with variable results, and not be feasible.

I wonder if the new Wifi Direct technologies provide anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

On Android you can use [Near Field Communication](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)

Comment: This is a reach, using NFC. . . . `set of short-range wireless technologies, typically requiring a distance of 4cm or less to initiate a connection`, since the distance is relatively short, using this would be very inefficient.